# Warning: file_put_contents : failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php

I am working with facebook graph api, in my code i want to store a user profile image url in my database & the image store in my database file, it can find the source file also show it but it can't store image my database. The error says that:

```
file_put_contents(celebrity_u_look_alike/youtube_star/fb_user_image/img_1264053943663652.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/smartcarsassocia/public_html/celebrity_u_look_alike/youtube_star/youtube_star.php on line 101
```

My source code shown below :

```
try {
        $requestPicture = $fb->get('/me/picture?redirect=false&height=250&width=250'); //getting user picture
        $requestProfile = $fb->get('/me'); // getting basic info


        $picture = $requestPicture->getGraphUser();
        $profile = $requestProfile->getGraphUser();
        $url= $picture['url'];
        echo $url;
        $filename = 'img_' . $profile_data['id'] . '.png';
        echo $filename;
        $path1 = "celebrity_u_look_alike/youtube_star/fb_user_image/" . basename($filename);
        $image_file = file_get_contents($url);
        file_put_contents($path1, $image_file );
        //file_put_contents($path2, file_get_contents($url));


    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        // When Graph returns an error
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        // When validation fails or other local issues
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because:

```
file_put_contents($path1, $image_file );
```

the path you have provided in `$path1` doesn't exist physically. So make sure the directory exist. If not, then create it using `mkdir()` function.

Comment: i keep a folder for store image. Path way  is [public_html/celebrity_u_look_alike/youtube_star/fb_user_image], i keep it  in my cpanel but it says failed to open stream.

Comment: So check the write permission on it.

Comment: i don't get it, will you please help me how can i write it down.

Comment: Check if the write file permission in there or not?

Comment: Thanks, i get it now.

Comment: Sounds great !!